# Number to words Mapping , Awe inspiring memory whim?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, logic

I need help for completing this little project

Program will take a phone number as an input and convert it into a proper English word.

Explaination:
There is some letters related to digits from 0-9 saved in a text file in first ten lines, something like

```
1 akl
2 dgh
3 qnm
4 rtu
5 zx
6 cvf
7 eip
8 wjs
9 yb
0 o
```

On line# 11 total number of words is present i-e 50000
after that, from line number 12 all 50000 words are present; one word per line.
Now program will take number(s) as an input form user until user enters -1

and then generate a proper English matching word from this text file.Each letter represents a digit from the list.

for example user enters
6182703

output will be :
Fashion

for more than 1 matching words , system will list all the words hyphen '-' seperated.

How should I start this, what approach should I use ?
If someone gives Pseudo code or hints .. It would be really great.

Comment: You may want to look into search. Start with brute force. When you get that working you can improve on it with some data structure magic (tries).

Comment: Do you have a length limit for the input in your application? Sounds fun btw :-)

Comment: not really, user can input any number , and more than one number at a time... yeah i feel the same , but bit confused , want to implement the best solution. :)

Comment: @Sobia this looks like a question I got somewhere at a recruitment test,I think we both have gone thru the same test :)

Answer (score 2):

I would take a dictionary of words and sort it in a file by your needs.

e.g:

apple = 17717

cherry = 627449

Then go through the file with a search algorithm.

EDIT: or you could store the data in a Relational DB (http://hsqldb.org/ is simple) to avoid a bigger memory footprint. If you like the solution you also could investigate some key/value stores etc.

Comment: +1, nice solution.  Need to be careful if using a Map (from the string of digits to the english word) to store the dictionary though, as many words might share the same digits.  Storing the dictionary as a Map<String, List<String>> would work well though.

Comment: Thanks @Martin and romedius for ur suggestions .. now things getting clearer on my mind :)

Answer (score 2):

A lot of the detail in your question relates to the input spec, which is all pretty trivial.

After parsing your input, you're going to have a list of "candidate" words (all the words), and a mapping of digits to the set of characters it can be represented with.

```
List<String> words;
Map<Character, Set<Character>> digitMapping;
```

The simplest way of generating the word for a number is probably this: sequentially filter the list of candidates, testing if they match the input digits, and removing them otherwise.  Something like this might do the trick (consider this pseudocode - I haven't tried compiling it):

```
List<String> getMatches(String inputDigits) {
    // Take a copy of the word list.  You don't want to ruin the list for the next caller
    List<String> candidates = new ArrayList<String>(words); 

    for (Iterator<String> it = candidates.iterator(); it.hasNext() && !candidats.isEmpty(); ) {
        String candidate = it.getNext();
        for (int i = 0; i < inputDigits.length; ++i) {
            Character c = new Character(candidate.charAt(i));
            Character d = new Character(inputDigits.charAt(i));
            if (!digitMapping.get(d).contains(c)) {   
                it.remove();
            }
         }
     }

     return candidates;
}
```

It will return all the words that match, so in your example, "555" will likely return an empty list.  "6182703" might only return a single word, "fashion", while "202" might return several words in a list ("dog", "hog", "god").  You'll need to decide how you want to handle the zero and multiple cases.

**Edit: Details on populating digitMapping**:

The digitMapping will be something like:

```
Map<Character, Set<Character>> digitMapping = new HashMap<Character, Set<Character>>();
```

Then you'll need to grab a char and a String from the input.  For the input line "1 akl", your char will be '1', while your String will be "akl".  You're mapping from the character to the set of characters in the string, so will need to construct an empty set, put it into the map, then populate the set.  Something like (again, I haven't even tried compiling this, so take it with a grain of salt):

```
private void addDigitToMap(char digit, String chars) {
    Set<Character> set = new HashSet<Character>();
    digitMapping.put(set);
    for (char c : chars.toCharArray()) {
        set.add(new Character(c));
    }
 }
```

So now the map will have an entry that points to a set of the characters it can be represented by.

Comment: One question martin how can I set value of Set<Character> in Map<Character, Set<Character>> , can you give me an example ? I have never done it before.